# Understanding Themes in Google BigQuery GDELT GKG 2.0

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

I'm using Google bigquery to analyze the GDELT GKG 2.0 [dataset](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg) and would like to better understand how to query based on themes (or V2Themes). The [docs](http://data.gdeltproject.org/documentation/GDELT-Global_Knowledge_Graph_Codebook-V2.1.pdf) mention a 'Category List' spreadsheet but so far I've been unsuccessful in finding that list.

the following asesome [blog](https://blog.gdeltproject.org/google-bigquery-gkg-2-0-sample-queries/) mentions that you can use World Bank Taxonomy among others to narrow down your search. My objective is to find all items that mention "droughts / too little water" ,all items that mention "floods / too much water" and all items that mention " poor quality / too dirty water" that have a geographical match on a sub-country level.

So far I've been able to get a list of distinct themes but this is non-extensive and I don't get the hierarchy / structure of it.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT theme
FROM (
  SELECT
    GKGRECORDID,
    locations,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(themes,r'(^.[^,]+)') AS theme,
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){0}([^#]*)') AS NUMERIC) AS location_type,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){1}([^#]*)') AS location_fullname,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){2}([^#]*)') AS location_countrycode,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){3}([^#]*)') AS location_adm1code,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){4}([^#]*)') AS location_adm2code,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){5}([^#]*)') AS location_latitude,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){6}([^#]*)') AS location_longitude,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){7}([^#]*)') AS location_featureid,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^(?:[^#]*#){8}([^#]*)') AS location_characteroffset,
    DocumentIdentifier
  FROM
    `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`,
    UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Locations,';')) AS locations,
    UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Themes,';')) AS themes
  WHERE
    _PARTITIONTIME >= "2018-08-20 00:00:00"
    AND _PARTITIONTIME < "2018-08-21 00:00:00" )
WHERE
  (location_type = 5
    OR location_type = 4
    OR location_type = 2) --WorldState, WorldCity or US State
ORDER BY
  theme
```

And a list of water related themes I've been able to find so far (sample, not exhaustive):

```
CRISISLEX_C06_WATER_SANITATION
ENV_WATERWAYS
HUMAN_RIGHTS_ABUSES_WATERBOARD
HUMAN_RIGHTS_ABUSES_WATERBOARDED
HUMAN_RIGHTS_ABUSES_WATERBOARDING
NATURAL_DISASTER_FLOODWATER
NATURAL_DISASTER_FLOODWATERS
NATURAL_DISASTER_FLOOD_WATER
NATURAL_DISASTER_FLOOD_WATERS
NATURAL_DISASTER_HIGH_WATER
NATURAL_DISASTER_HIGH_WATERS
NATURAL_DISASTER_WATER_LEVEL
TAX_AIDGROUPS_WATERAID
TAX_DISEASE_WATERBORNE_DISEASE
TAX_DISEASE_WATERBORNE_DISEASES
TAX_FNCACT_WATERBOY
TAX_FNCACT_WATERMAN
TAX_FNCACT_WATERMEN
TAX_FNCACT_WATER_BOY
TAX_WEAPONS_WATER_CANNON
TAX_WEAPONS_WATER_CANNONS
TAX_WORLDBIRDS_WATERFOWL
TAX_WORLDMAMMALS_WATER_BUFFALO
UNGP_CLEAN_WATER_SANITATION
WATER_SECURITY
WB_1000_WATER_MANAGEMENT_STRUCTURES
WB_1021_WATER_LAW
WB_1063_WATER_ALLOCATION_AND_WATER_SUPPLY
WB_1064_WATER_DEMAND_MANAGEMENT
WB_1199_WATER_SUPPLY_AND_SANITATION
WB_1215_WATER_QUALITY_STANDARDS
WB_137_WATER
WB_138_WATER_SUPPLY
WB_139_SANITATION_AND_WASTEWATER
WB_140_AGRICULTURAL_WATER_MANAGEMENT
WB_141_WATER_RESOURCES_MANAGEMENT
WB_143_RURAL_WATER
WB_144_URBAN_WATER
WB_1462_WATER_SANITATION_AND_HYGIENE
WB_149_WASTEWATER_TREATMENT_AND_DISPOSAL
WB_150_WASTEWATER_REUSE
WB_155_WATERSHED_MANAGEMENT
WB_156_GROUNDWATER_MANAGEMENT
WB_159_TRANSBOUNDARY_WATER
WB_1729_URBAN_WATER_FINANCIAL_SUSTAINABILITY
WB_1731_NON_REVENUE_WATER
WB_1778_FRESHWATER_ECOSYSTEMS
WB_1790_INTERNATIONAL_WATERWAYS
WB_1798_WATER_POLLUTION
WB_1805_WATERWAYS
WB_1998_WATER_ECONOMICS
WB_2008_WATER_TREATMENT
WB_2009_WATER_QUALITY_MONITORING
WB_2971_WATER_PRICING
WB_2981_DRINKING_WATER_QUALITY_STANDARDS
WB_2992_FRESHWATER_FISHERIES
WB_427_WATER_ALLOCATION_AND_WATER_ECONOMICS
```

Answer (score 9):

While this link is provided as a theme listing:

http://data.gdeltproject.org/documentation/GDELT-Global_Knowledge_Graph_CategoryList.xlsx

...it is far from complete (perhaps just the original theme list?). I just pulled a single day's worth of GKG, and there are tons of themes not on the list of 283 themes in that spreadsheet.

GKG documentation located at https://blog.gdeltproject.org/world-bank-group-topical-taxonomy-now-in-gkg/ points to a World Bank Taxonomy located at http://pubdocs.worldbank.org/en/275841490966525495/Theme-Taxonomy-and-definitions.pdf. The GKG post implies this World Bank taxonomy has been rolled into the GKG theme list.

This is presented as a complete listing of World Bank Taxonomy themes. Unfortunately, I've found numerous World Bank themes in GKG that aren't in this publication. The union of these two lists represents a portion of GKG themes, but it definitely isn't all of them.

Comment: Note: If you look at the World Bank 'WBG Topical Taxonomy' and click 'VIEW MORE', certain vocabulary words will mention that they have a corresponding GDELT theme name.  For example, [Immunizations](http://vocabulary.worldbank.org/taxonomy/1459.html) links to `HEALTH_VACCINATION`

Comment: Notably, the [UK Office for National Statistics references this stack overflow Q&A](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/deaths/methodologies/globaldatabaseofeventslanguageandtonegdeltappendix) when stating that "There are thousands of different GKG themes, but no complete list seems to be provided anywhere."

Answer (score 3):

Here is the list of GKG Themes:

http://data.gdeltproject.org/documentation/GDELT-Global_Knowledge_Graph_CategoryList.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

The best GDELT GKG Themes list I could find is [here](http://data.gdeltproject.org/api/v2/guides/LOOKUP-GKGTHEMES.TXT), as described in [this blog post](https://blog.gdeltproject.org/new-august-2019-gkg-2-0-themes-lookup/).

I put it into a `CSV` file, which I find slightly easier to work with, and put that file [here](https://github.com/CatoMinor/GDELT-GKG-Themes).

Comment: There is an updated blog post, as I found to be the latest: blog.gdeltproject.org/new-november-2021-gkg-2-0-themes-lookup This links to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs this, I have added a list of all themes in the GKG v1 in the timeperiod from 1/1/2017-31/12/2020 which are at least present in 10 or more articles for that particular day: [Themes.parquet](https://github.com/oeyvindds/examples/blob/master/ThemesKomplettListe.parquet)

It consists of 17639 unique themes with the count per day. Looks like this:

[image]

The complete numbers for that 4 year dataset is 36 713 385 unique actors, 50 845 unique themes as well as 26 389 528 unique organizations. These numbers are not filtered for different spellings for the same entity, and hence Donald Trump and Donald J. Trump will count as two separate actors.

Answer (score 1):

V2Themes include different taxonomies. Here is an initial list:

- Crisislex [link](https://blog.gdeltproject.org/crisislex-taxonomies-now-available-in-gkg/) -> themes starting with "CRISISLEX"
- United Nations Global Pulse [link](https://blog.gdeltproject.org/un-my-world-survey-topics-added-to-gkg-2-0/) / [GP](https://post2015.unglobalpulse.net/)  -> themes starting with "UNGP"
- The World Bank [pdf](https://thedocs.worldbank.org/en/doc/275841490966525495-0290022017/original/NewThemeTaxonomyanddefinitionsrevisedJuly012016.pdf) / [taxonomy description](https://vocabulary.worldbank.org/taxonomy/1737.html) -> themes starting with "WB"